# VB Convert 2 DataRows to a Single String in an Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

My Goal is to take two rows(FirstName and Surname) Convert them to a single Array of "FirstName, Surname".

This is my terrible code i eventually put together

```
Private Sub Search_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DbaPatientDataSet.tblPatientData' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblPatientDataTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbaPatientDataSet.tblPatientData)

    listFirst.DataSource = Me.TblPatientDataBindingSource
    listFirst.DisplayMember = "FirstName"
    listLast.DataSource = Me.TblPatientDataBindingSource
    listLast.DisplayMember = "Surname"

    Dim Lenth As Integer = Me.listFirst.Items.Count - 1
    Dim count As Integer = 1

    Dim ArrFirst(Lenth) As String
    Dim ArrLast(Lenth) As String

    For count = 1 To Lenth

        ArrFirst(count) = listFirst.Items(count).ToString
        ArrLast(count) = listLast.Items(count).ToString

    Next count

    count = 1

    For count = 1 To Lenth
        arrFullName(count) = ArrLast(count) & ", " & ArrFirst(count)
    Next count

    'Arrays Set =====================================================
```

But with this code i get an Array of

```
`"Sytem.Data.DataRowView, Sytem.Data.DataRowView"
 "Sytem.Data.DataRowView, Sytem.Data.DataRowView"
 "Sytem.Data.DataRowView, Sytem.Data.DataRowView"
"Sytem.Data.DataRowView, Sytem.Data.DataRowView"
`
```

As you can see
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ8kG.png)

There must be an easy way to convert both `DataRows` to strings then `concatenate` them together in an array

I am going to search this array using a Binary Search to find a desired name

Thanks

Comment: create a `string` variable, after you load data , pass both firstname and surname to the variable..Then do what u wanna do wid it...isn't it obvious ?

Comment: One of the problems with Google-Paste code is that you dont really understand what it does.  DataBinding - using a DataSource - wraps the DB Data in a DataView.  Its a bit unclear why you bind the same DS to different controls, but you could.should get the data from where it is - the BindingSource

Comment: Plutonix i didn't copy paste that i just started entering names related to the database until it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there is an answer but for now you could go direct to the data table to get what you need.

```
        Dim arrNames(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim dt As DataTable = DbaPatientDataSet.Tables(0)
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            arrNames(i) = $"{row("Surname")}, {row("FirstName")}"
            i += 1
        Next
        For Each item In arrNames
            Debug.Print(item)
        Next
        'assume the names of your columns are Surname and FirstName
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you are confusing your rows and your columns. You have 2 columns. I went directly to full name but I think you can break it out if you need to.

```
        Dim arrNames(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            arrNames(i) = $"{ListBox1.Items(i)} {ListBox2.Items(i)}"
        Next
        For Each item In arrNames
            Debug.Print(item)
        Next
```

The string with the $ in front is an interpolated string. Sort of an improvement to String.Format.

Comment: Its Still outputting Sytem.Data.DataRowView Sytem.Data.DataRowView instead of John Smith

Comment: Very sorry, I don't work with bound controls very often

Comment: I know I have seen this before and there is an answer. In the mean time you can get what you need directly form the Data Table.

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code up, I get the result you are looking for, so I'm not sure what you are missing. In saying that though, you are making things hard on yourself by messing around with arrays :). Just use the dataset rows directly - they are strongly typed and you can check for nulls etc as needed... something like this;

```
    Dim fullNames As New List(Of String) '-- or you could fill your array.
    For Each row As DbaPatientDataSet.tblPatientDataRow In ds.tblPatientData
        fullNames.Add(row.Surname & ", " & row.FirstName)
    Next
```

Just looking at what you are trying to achieve, if it was me, I would be bringing back the formatted data in my query that fills the dataset i.e. a third, FullName, column.

Answer (score 0):

It has been in the back of my mind. Finally got it for the List Box directly.

```
        Dim arrFullNames(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each item As DataRowView In ListBox1.Items
            arrFullNames(i) = $"{DirectCast(item("Surname"), String)}, {DirectCast(item("Firstname"), String)}"
            i += 1
        Next
        For Each item As String In arrFullNames
            Debug.Print(item)
        Next
```